# Configure jenkins to deploy artifact to one of shared location (Win)

Tags: jenkins

Deploy an artifact in shared location where the target is not a host but our network path on our laptop c:/sharedpath.how do we configure jenkins to deploy the artifact to the network path.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [publish-over-cifs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-cifs/) Jenkins plugin which can:

> Send build artifacts to a windows share (CIFS/SMB/samba)

Comment: Thank you but what values should be given for wins server  and for cisf, it will be the name of the host where the shared location path is resided.

Comment: That is documented on the linked page. For wins the ip address of the server, for cifs either ip or hostname

Comment: Hi Henrik, I have given the server up address.On testing the configuration,got an error like "jenkins.pluginss.publish_over.bappublisherexception:exception when testing config.URL (smb://hostname/sharwd_path),message:(the network name cannot be found)

Comment: That is probably caused by a network problem. Your Jenkins worker node must have a route to the smb host.